How does catboost handle np.inf values during training?
I want to know how how catboost handles np.inf values during training? Are they ignored completely or are they treated as a separate value/category?
Can training a model on data that contains np.inf values cause any problem and is it generally recommended to handle them before training?
I expected that np.inf values would be treated the same as np.nan values, but when I replace np.inf with np.nan in my test set the pretrained model (trained on values with np.inf) is giving different probability outputs. I couldn't find any information regarding this topic in the documentation.
